# How can I make the files I have put in the htdocs folder editable again?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, permissions, operating-system

I am doing a project for my computer science class at school. I have done a majority of my website but then started to run into a few issues that (I think) were solved by moving my code files into the htdocs file within xampp/lampp. However, now I am unable to edit the files as I have insufficient permissions. I have set my account as the root user and have tried to save the files as the superuser (as prompted by vscode) but even then vscode is denied permission to write the files. I am very new to xampp, using the mac terminal and coding in general so I'm sorry if anything in this post is unclear, it is probably as a result of my lack of understanding. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see&save what the permissions of your files and folders are

`ls -lR <your_code_dir_name> > old_permissions.txt`

We will now try to change the owner of the files:

`sudo chown -R <your-vs-user-name> <your_code_dir_name>`

you can see your user if you run `whoami`

If something goes wrong, you can always go back to the previous permissions you backed up.

Use wisdom in running these commands. Be careful not to run them on important system folders

Comment: Thanks, for the help, I am a bit confused in what goes into <your-vs-user-name>, should it just be the account I want to give ownership of the files? I am also confused what the code directory is. Should it be htdocs or my folder within htdocs that contains the code?

Comment: Run `ps -aux` and serach for the user under vs code its 'your-vs-user-name' I guess the command `whoami` can help find the user. Simply the first option is better so we can be sure.   <your_code_dir_name> The folder inside htdocs. If the answer helped you, I would be happy if you could mark the question as "Resolved". @JackMatthews

Comment: If my answer helps you, please mark this question as resolved.